# calling ajax before submitting the form

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I want to create a login screen in which,on the click of button the ajax verify the password and then then submit the form.but when i click submit button the form is submitted before the ajax call
in short the action method and ajax both call on the same button click,but i want to call ajax before action method

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "AccountAP", FormMethod.Post))

{

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="login-box">
            <div class="login-logo">
                <!-- /.login-logo -->
                <div class="login-box-body">
                    <center><a href="#"><img src="img/ra_logo.png" class="img-responsive" width="128" height="128" /></a></center>
                    <br />
                    <p class="login-box-msg" style="font-size:20px !important;">Sign in to start your session</p>
                    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Email" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Password" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <!-- /.col -->
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right btn-block btn-flat" value="Sign In" id="btnSave"/>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.col -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.login-box-body -->
            </div>
        </div>
}
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#btnSave').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.alert("what's up");
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Make an Ajax call to check the password and in the `success` callback call the `submit` function of your `form`.

Comment: Do you see any error in your browser's console? If there is any error, then the javascript breaks and the function is submitted by default as a normal form is submitted.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ thats all i want to do,

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj no sign of error,just form is submitting on button click, before script run

Comment: You might not be seeing any error in console because before you see it, the page would refresh. Can you check the `preserve log` checkbox if you are on chrome or `persist` tab if you are on firefox and then check if there's any error?

Answer (score 0):

**Check below code for that :**

**First Method :**

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "AccountAP", FormMethod.Post,new { id= "submitForm" }))
{
 <div class="col-xs-12">
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right btn-block btn-flat" value="Sign In" id="btnSave"/>
  </div>
}

<script>
$(function () {
 $("#btnSave").click(function(){
 //Code for ajax verify the password then call below submitForm after validation 
          
       $("#submitForm").submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

**Second Method :**

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login","AccountAP",FormMethod.Post, new { onsubmit = "myJsFunction()" }))
```

**Your jquery code should be :**

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#btnSave").submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
           e.alert("what's up");
          //Code for ajax verify the password then call below myJsFunction after validation 
           myJsFunction();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I will suggest to capture the submit event on the form, instead of the click event on the submit button. Because people can not only submit your form by clicking the submit button, but also hitting the enter key in a textarea...etc
2. You will need to stop the default browser behavior of the submit event you capture so that whenever a for is submitted, browser won't post your form. In jQuery, you can stop default by doing event.preventDefault();